# How to read state inside event listener?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
//...
    const [ scale, setScale ] = useState(0.5);

    const [ altPressed, setAltPressed ] = useState(false);

    const handleScroll = ({ deltaY }) => {
        if (altPressed) {
            const newScale = scale + deltaY;

            setScale(newScale);
        }
    };

    const handleKeyPress = ({ altKey }) => {
        if (altKey) {
            setAltPressed(true);
        }
    };

    const handleKeyRelease = ({ altKey }) => {
        if (!altKey) {
            setAltPressed(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyRelease);
    }, []);
//...
```

But unfortunately `handleScroll` always read the initial state of `altPressed`, which is false, even though the keyboard event listeners are working fine, and setting the states correctly.

How to solve this issue so it will always read the fresh state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it is to make your effect depend on `altPressed`, so that the event listeners will be recreated when it changes. You must make sure you remove the event listeners in a function returned from the function given to `useEffect` as well so you don't get any duplicated listeners or memory leaks.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyRelease);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyRelease);
  };
}, [altPressed]);
```

Comment: Another option would be to combine the two separate states via [`useReducer()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), since they are somewhat coupled.